# Difference-in-differences - Binary data

Tags: regression, logistic, t-test, binary-data, difference-in-difference

I am working on an exercise using conversion rate data on a travel website. The conversion rate is defined as the number of users in a given time period that make a purchase.

There are two groups, A and B. I am trying to understand if a new feature released to group B had an impact on conversion rate. There are underlying differences between the two groups (causes unknown). I therefore wish to take a difference-in-differences approach using data prior to the feature release, and after the feature release.

The data is as follows:

| testGroup | timeGroup | users | conversions | cvr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | pre-test | 18350 | 550 | 0.036 |
| A | test | 19441 | 782 | 0.040 |
| B | pre-test | 19824 | 835 | 0.042 |
| B | test | 18963 | 946 | 0.050 |

I am familiar with using OLS regression to analyse difference-in-differences for a continuous metric (for example - revenue). However, I am looking to understand how I can do the same for a binomial metric.

Specifically:

- Can a t-test (or similar) be applied to the aggregate conversion rates to understand the significance (or lack thereof) of the difference-in-difference value. If so, how is 'sample size' defined given we have 4 groups but 2 differences to compare
- Can a logistic (or similar) regression model be applied to these aggregate values. In this case, how would the variance (and therefore P value), be calculated

Note that the parallel trends assumption has been validated using a daily breakdown of the data. However, due to the nature of conversion rates, the daily values are not equal to the aggregate values (for example - a customer could visit the website on multiple days but only convert once, hence the aggregated conversion rate will not equal the daily conversion rate).

Answer (score 0):

Often in a 'difference-in-differences' design
the differences in the A group are paired and
also the differences in the B group are paired.
I see no pairing here. The pre and post results
in A may be from unrelated randomly chosen subjects
and similarly from B. [BTW, your conversions rate for A-pre seems incorrect:
$550/18\,350 \approx 0.030].$

So this is not a standard D in D
design. I will show one possible way to look at your
data, but I will not be surprised if others have
alternative suggestions.

In A, treating the pre and post proportions (0.03 and 0.04) as
if from independent 'conversions' in the R procedure `prop.test`
we find them to be highly significantly different (P-value near 0) with a
95% confidence interval $(0.0065, 0,0140)$ for the difference.

```
prop.test(c(782, 550), c(19441, 18350), cor=F)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(782, 550) out of c(19441, 18350)
X-squared = 29.175, df = 1, p-value = 6.613e-08
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.006548142 0.013954890
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.04022427 0.02997275
```

Similarly, in B the two proportions (0.042 and 0.050) are highly
significantly different with CI $(0.0036,0.0199)$ for the difference.

```
    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    without continuity correction

data:  c(946, 835) out of c(18963, 19824)
X-squared = 13.343, df = 1, p-value = 0.0002595
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.003592234 0.011939685
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.04988662 0.04212066
```

Thus, the confidence intervals for the gains in A and B overlap.
Conversion rates increased significantly from pre to post in both
groups, but not by remarkably different amounts. (For example, one could argue that the true conversion rate in both groups may have increased by about 0.9%.)

Answer (score 0):

Non-linear DD analyses have been used and proposed in econometrics, but they are surprisingly rare in applied papers. This is probably because OLS, or more generally Normal/linear theory, is often used even for binary or proportional data. So the DD is simply estimated in the "normal probability model".

You might be interested in the application of logit and probit models for estimating a DD by [Blundell et al. (2004)](https://academic.oup.com/jeea/article-abstract/2/4/569/2280805). In addition, look up the paper by [Woolridge (2023)](https://academic.oup.com/ectj/article-abstract/26/3/C31/7250479?redirectedFrom=fulltext). He sets up a whole framework of DD estimators based on generalized linear models for binary and count outcomes.

Note one important implication: when you apply a link function to the expected values in your groups, as in the approaches proposed in above papers, you are assuming that counterfactual parallel trends **hold on that transformed scale**. The paper by J. Woolridge discusses the assumptions in detail. So, for example, you can simultaneously assume parallel trends on, say, a logit scale, but reject it on the linear probability scale. Which one is the correct specification should be an informed choice. In this regards, your statement...

> Note that the parallel trends assumption has been validated using a daily breakdown of the data.

...is (i) incomplete, because there is no information on the underlying transformation you are applying to the daily means, (ii) misleading, because the parallel trends assumption in the DD design is about **counterfactual** trends, which are inherently unobserved, so it cannot be checked. Probably you are referring to the "pre-trends" only.

Finally, the use of model-based estimators is primarily motivated by the need for regression adjustment for additional covariates or for analyzing many time points and including time fixed effects (which might be of interest in your case, because it seems you have daily data). If you do not need/want to adjust your analysis, you can do inference on the above contingency tables alone (similar to the approach by BruceET). To test formally for a difference in difference in proportions, you can take a look at the literature and R function in [my respository](https://github.com/stefgehrig/prop_interact). (But I'm not saying there might be better tests that are also model-free). The test confirms the non-significance of the interaction term:

```
df <- data.frame(testGroup = c(rep("A", 18350 + 19441), rep("B", 19824 + 18963)),
                 timeGroup = c(rep("pre-test", 18350), rep("test", 19441), rep("pre-test", 19824), rep("test", 18963)),
                 c_outcome = c(rep(1, 550), rep(0,18350-550),
                               rep(1, 782), rep(0,19441-782),
                               rep(1, 835), rep(0,19824-835),
                               rep(1, 946), rep(0,18963-946)))
prop_interact(
  data     = df,
  main     = "timeGroup",
  interact = "testGroup",
  outcome  = "c_outcome",
  variance = "Wilson"
)

$`results for each level`
 testGroup prop.in.pre-test prop.in.test n.in.pre-test n.in.test       
varsum   prop.diff
1         A        0.9700272    0.9597757         18350     19441 3.574196e-06 0.010251516
2         B        0.9578793    0.9501134         19824     18963 4.538043e-06 0.007765959

$statistic
[1] "0.762 (df = 1)"

$`p interaction`
[1] 0.3828394
```